# Additive Theory of sets and enumerability of cantor set

Tags: combinatorics, cantor-set

Let $S$ denote de cantor set on $[0,1]$ then $S$  is non enumerable.

Sketch: Assume by contradiction that $S$ is enumerable then by additive theory of sets the sum $A+B$ = {$a+b: a\in A, b\in B$} is enumerable if both $A,B$ are enumerable,but then $S+S=[0,2]$is non-enumerable,contradiction.

Is that a reasonable alternative for the Cantor's diagonal proof?

Comment: It seems ok to me.

Comment: To be completely self-contained, you should justify why $S+S=[0, 2]$.

Comment: However, while it easily yields that $\#S>\aleph_0$, it uses heavily the axiom of choice when it comes to prove that $\#S=2^{\aleph_0}$, because you kind of need the fact that $\kappa^2=\kappa$ for all cardinals $\aleph_0\le \kappa<2^{\aleph_0}$. Which is a bit of a shame, since the base-$3$ description of $S$ immediately provides an injective function $2^{\Bbb N}\hookrightarrow S$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli No, there is absolutely no use of choice in the proof that $|S|=2^{\aleph_0}$. It does not need to use the fact you indicate.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Is there a general theorem that says that $A+A$ is an interval only if $\#A=\beth_1$? I did not know that.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli You do not need that fact to prove that the Cantor set has the size of the reals.

Comment: By the way, I do not see how this is an alternative to Cantor's diagonal proof, since the argument is using explicitly that $[0,2] $ is uncountable.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo I know that you do not need AC. That was my point: the proof in the OP works fine for proving that Cantor is uncountable, but it cannot be adapted to prove that Cantor is in bijection with $\Bbb R$ without AC or some form of CH. And this is a shame, because one could just as easily prove directly the latter and obtain the former as a corollary.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Again, no extra assumption or even choice is needed to prove that the Cantor set is in bijection with the reals, though of course an argument (not in the proof sketched in the question) is needed for that. Anyway,  the proof sketched does not even give us that the Cantor set is uncountable unless one already knows that the reals themselves are uncountable.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo In order to prove that it is uncountable I may (and it is rather an overkill) use baire cathegory theorem in order to avoid the diagonal argument,its feasible but questionable,either way I just wanted to find new ways to prove it.Thanks for your relevant observation.